# Any suggestion to DRY this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, helper

```
<col class="psap-msisdn-col"></col>
<col class="from-col"></col>
<col class="psap-name-col"></col>
<col class="rh-sip-uri-col"></col>
<col class="psap-message-col"></col>
<col class="dlg-time-col"></col>
<col></col>
```

Any better ways ?

Comment: I don't see a way to DRY, because I don't see anything repeated :)

Comment: it can be shortened definitely, but i see that you tagged "helper", doing a helper for this might be an overkill...

Answer (score 3):

do you mean something like this?

```
<% ["psap-msisdn-col", "from-col", ... etc].each do |klass| %>
  <col class="<%=klass%>"></col>
<% end %>
<col></col>
```

Comment: or perhaps `<% %w(psap-msisdn-col from-col .. ).each do ||%>`